# SinchService integration using Cocoapods failing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, sinch, podfile

I'm new to Sinch service, currently I'm trying to use 'SinchService' along with 'SinchRTC' via Cocoapods but Xcode is giving me this error:

***Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Sinch", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SINService.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SinchService)

"_SINApplicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification", referenced from:
      -[SINService initWithConfig:] in SINService.o
      -[SINService dealloc] in SINService.o

"_SINClientDidFailNotification", referenced from:
      -[SINSClientsObserver init] in SINSClientsObserver.o
      -[SINSClientsObserver dealloc] in SINSClientsObserver.o

"_SINClientDidStartNotification", referenced from:
      -[SINSClientsObserver init] in SINSClientsObserver.o
      -[SINSClientsObserver dealloc] in SINSClientsObserver.o

"_SINClientWillTerminateNotification", referenced from:
      -[SINSClientsObserver init] in SINSClientsObserver.o
      -[SINSClientsObserver dealloc] in SINSClientsObserver.o

"_SINRemoteNotificationKey", referenced from:
      -[SINService onDidReceiveRemoteNotification:] in SINService.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)***

When I remove 'SinchService' from my Podfile no error is throw by Xcode. Help with this issue would be appreciate.

My podfile:

*platform :ios, '8.4'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

target 'Conversa' do

pod 'ParseUI'

pod 'Parse'

pod 'SinchService'

pod 'SinchRTC'

pod 'YapDatabase/SQLCipher'

pod 'GoogleMaps'

pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'

pod 'Whisper'

pod 'OHQBImagePicker'

pod 'Buglife'

pod 'Branch'

pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'

pod 'JVFloatLabeledTextField'

pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'

pod 'Appirater'

pod 'IDMPhotoBrowser'

pod 'CRToast', '~> 0.0.7'

pod 'Fabric'

pod 'Crashlytics'

pod 'SSKeychain'

pod 'Mantle', '~> 2.0'

pod 'DGActivityIndicatorView'

end*

Answer (score 1):

It require following Frameworks to be added in Link Library.[image]

Comment: Still getting the same error, this is how Link Libraries look like: ![Link Binary With Libraries](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aq2h2Ztvc5MS6kDYjhXaXN4vRT5i).